# 3D perspective on maps in Leaflet, CartoDB?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, 3d, carto

Are there any JS library out there that would render normal, flat maps (like Leaflet) into a perspective map like this one, on the web:

[image]

Also, anyone seen anything that could turn CartoDB data into 3D representation, like this?

Comment: I'm not sure about integration with cartodb, but I recently saw [this post](http://anitagraser.com/2014/03/15/3d-viz-with-qgis-three-js/) about making 3D maps from QGIS using the [three.js](http://threejs.org/) library.  You may want to take a look at that.

Comment: See also: [Three.js + leaflet = 3D maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682551/three-js-leaflet-3d-maps) on StackOverflow

Comment: And a couple of articles to look into: [Render Geographic Information in 3D With Three.js and D3.js](http://css.dzone.com/articles/render-geographic-information), and [Showing GPS tracks in 3D with three.js and d3.js](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/11/showing-gps-tracks-in-3d-with-threejs.html)

Comment: Maybe you find this visualization useful: http://pluto.cartodb.com/viz/bf4dacd4-003c-11e3-aaf8-a9294e572fad/embed_map

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you could use [Osmbuildings](http://osmbuildings.org/). Its a JavaScript library for visualizing OpenStreetMaps (or custom GeoJSON) building geometry into a 3D perspective.

[image: OSMbuildingJS]

It use OpenStreetMaps data directly. Just add the loadData() method:

```
var map = new L.Map('map').setView([52.50440, 13.33522], 17);
var osmb = new OSMBuildings(map).loadData();
L.control.layers({}, { Buildings:osmb }).addTo(map); // add to layer switcher (optional)
```

Or, you could load your own GeoJSON. Just change the loadData() method to the setData(geojson):

```
var osmb = new OSMBuildings(map).setData(geoJSON);
```

Your data need to have a height property, and you can change the wall and roof color dynamically:

```
osmb.setStyle({ 
     wallColor:'rgba(100, 100, 250, 0.701961)', 
     roofColor:'rgb(220, 220, 50)', 
     shadows:true 
});
```

And even change the shadow perspective by setting daytime:

```
osmb.setDate(new Date(2014, 3, 24, 13, 0));
```

Comment: The current version of OSM Buildings (0.2.2b) does not support `setData` method, but `set` works! It tjus becomes: `var osmb = new OSMBuildings(map).setData(geoJSON);
`

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the primary use-cases for ViziCities (3D cities in the browser powered by OpenStreetMap), although the data layers aren't currently working yet. Perhaps something to consider for the future: https://github.com/robhawkes/vizicities

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of ViziCities

Comment: Cool project! Also, while it is fairly obvious that this is a project you are affiliated with, you might want to just make that a little more clear (even if it's open source).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a non-WebGL solution.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to give you a heads-up.

Comment: Does this version have the plots or any improved version?

Answer (score 2):

You can use OSM2world to pass 2D data from OpenStreetMap (map.osm) to 3D objects (map.obj), then use another converter ([convert_obj_three.py](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py)) to convert it into a threejs JSON model (map.js), and then use it in a threejs scene.

You can see how here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6LbKH6NnZU

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this requires WebGL, right?

Comment: Threejs it's a javascript library/api that take advantage of WebGL. But in the code you only have to include two libs: three.js and OrbitControls.js (this it's to manage the camera orbit).

Comment: and yes, threejs only works in browsers supported by WebGL.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've seen is the work of [Mike Bostock](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/).

He has a really cool map which has a kind of [oblique projection](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/03/01/world/americas/border-graphic.html?_r=0).

But there's nothing that makes it easy. D3 does my head in with respect to setting up projections. You can make amazing things if you work at it though.

Comment: OK, how does Mike do that?? Thanks for tip

Comment: Like this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3790444

Answer (score 1):

http://osm2world.org/ works without WebGL, but uses Java instead of js.

Designed for output of Openstreetmap buildings data, it should be adoptable for other 3D data as well.

The output is a slippy map similar to leaflet: http://maps.osm2world.org/

Answer (score 1):

Well, with CartoDB you can do something like this http://andrewxhill.com/cartodb-examples/scroll-story/pluto/index.html#4

You have to use this CartoCSS parameter:
{
building-height: 512; 
}

More info here:
https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-pluto